# Как убрать подсветку тега <a> при наведении

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать так, чтобы ссылка с тегом `<a href="...">Text</a>` при наведении никак не реагировала на курсор.
Я уже сделал:

```
a:hover {
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Но цвет по прежнему меняется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

что бы цвет не изменялся при наведений покрасьте его в тот цвет который был до наведения

```
a:hover {
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: Ну точно :) Гениальное просто. Спасибо

Comment: И как я заметил, `cursor` и `text-decoration` в `:hover` можно не указывать, достаточно это указать только в `a { ... }`

Comment: если помог можете ответить  как правильный ответ